# How can I fix unable to resolve module @react-navigation/native-stack?

Tags: react-native, mobile

I get this error: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/brwmY.png).
I´ve tried to run two commands of troubleshooting in React Navigation section, but it didn´t work.

I tried to run two commands using the troubleshooting section in React Navigation but they didn´t fix the error.

I ran these commands:

1. `npx react-native start --reset-cache`
2. `rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-\*`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` inside your **Android/Sdk/platform-tools** folder.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#method-1-using-adb-reverse-recommended-2